# The servlet does not respond to my post request

Tags: servlets

My training project is tennis scoreboard and I have met some problem. I created HTML page where 2 players send their name and then servlet takes the request and sends it to service layer which is then saved in database. The problem is that the servlet does not respond to my post request. I send two names through post request. I checked through chrome dev tools and the request was 200 OK, but my post servlet does not respond(in debugging too). Can someone help out? I am a bit new to all of this.
Here is web.xml:

```
<web-app>
  <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>servlets.NewMatch</servlet-name>
    <jsp-file>/new-match.jsp</jsp-file>
    <servlet-class>servlets.NewMatch</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>servlets.NewMatch</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/new-match</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Here is HTML page:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>New Match</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Player Registration</h1>
    <form method="post" action="/TennisScoreBoard_war_exploded/new-match">
            <label for="player1-name">Enter name of Player 1
                <input id="player1-name" type="text"  name="player1Name" required>
                </label>
            <label for="player2-name">Enter name of Player 2
                <input id="player2-name" type="text"  name="player2Name" required>
            </label>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name = "servlets.NewMatch", value = "/new-match")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class NewMatch extends HttpServlet {
    private  final PlayerService playerService;
    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        playerService.createPlayers(request,response);
    }
}
```

Comment: This question should include more details and clarify the problem. If there's an error then you should add it to the question. Saying it just doesn't work is not a problem.

Comment: @BalusC can you point it out please( i do not see a problem)

Comment: The `<jsp-file>` entry is the cause of the observable problem. It doesn't belong there and it's overriding the `<servlet-class>`. But you can just remove all this XML config. It's unnecessary when you already use `@WebServlet` annotation.